# Using comparison in useEffect's dependency array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a search input with a submit button and a clear button. When submit button is clicked, it will trigger a search request with available input value. When clear button is clicked, it will also trigger a search request with empty value. I try to use comparison in useEffect dependency array to trigger effect when the search value is empty to accomodate the clear button.

```js
const Test = ({ doGetData }) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
  const [activePage, setActivePage] = useState(1);
  const [term, setTerm] = useState("");

  const handleFilter = () => {
    const query = {
      page: activePage,
      q: term,
      active: status
    };
    doGetData(query);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleFilter();
  }, [status, activePage, term === ""]);

  const setEmptySearch = () => setTerm("");

  const handleInputChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.currentTarget;
    setTerm(value);
  };

  return (
    <SearchInput
      handleFilter={handleFilter}
      handleDismissSearch={setEmptySearch}
      handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
      status={status}
      term={term}
    />
  );
 };
```

It worked well when I click search button, click the clear button, and also when I manually erase the input.But, the only problem I have is when I type the first letter, it will trigger the search. Can you help me guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check with an if-statement inside of your useEffect-function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(term === "") {
    handleFilter();
  }
}, [status, activePage, term]);
```